# Importing different Django projects settings

Tags: python, django, import, settings

I am trying to import different `Django` projects **settings** file from the same python module.

```
project_path = ["/home/Desktop/test1", "/home/Desktop/test2", "/home/Desktop/test3"]
for j, i in enumerate(project_path):
    if os.path.exists(i):
        sys.path.append(i)
        os.system("fm -rf " + project_path[j - 1] + "/settings.pyc")
        import settings
        print "settings file path>>>", settings.__file__
        project_directory = os.path.dirname(settings.__file__)
        print "Application direcotry>>>", project_directory
        project_name = os.path.basename(project_directory)
        print "Application name>>>", project_name
        sys.path.append(os.path.join(project_directory, '..'))
        project_module = __import__(project_name, '', '', [''])
        # Set DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE appropriately.
        sys.path.remove(i)
```

and I am getting the following results:

```
settings file path>>> home/Desktop/test1/settings.pyc
Application direcotry>>> home/Desktop/test1
Application name>>> test1
settings file path>>> home/Desktop/test1/settings.pyc
Application direcotry>>> home/Desktop/test1
Application name>>> test1
settings file path>>> home/Desktop/test1/settings.pyc
Application direcotry>>> home/Desktop/test1
Application name>>> test1
```

My question is even I am removing the projects path and appending new one then also it is importing the same application path. So I am not able to import the next application path.

I even tried to reload the settings file.

```
import settings
settings = reload(settings)
```

Comment: Where did you put this importing python module? Under folder of 'home/Desktop/test1'?

Comment: No the script module is in different directory in "/tmp"

Comment: Looks like a xy problem (http://xyproblem.info/) to me. Care to explain why you're trying to do this ?

Comment: I am trying to the change password of all users of my different application by one script. The password will be same for all user. I am importing settings because I want to import user table to change the password for each user.

Answer (score 0):

Try to import with package name and comment unrelevant lines.
Make sure folder test1/test2/test3 is package first. If not, add `__init__.py` inside the folder.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-

import sys

project_path = ["/home/Desktop/test1", "/home/Desktop/test2", "/home/Desktop/test3"]

for path in project_path:

    sys.path.append(path)
    package_name = path.split('/')[2]

    cmd = 'import ' + package_name + '.settings'
    sys.path.remove(path)
```

Comment: But how come it will work for the first iteration as you have executed import settings command at the end.

Comment: @TanveerAlam You don't have settings.py in the path?

Comment: No, I am appending the project directory path in sys path inside which settings.py exists and that i'm trying to import it.

Comment: @TanveerAlam Check my update. You don't have to delete pyc file every time.

Comment: @ m170897017 Getting 'ImportError: No module named test1.settings'

Comment: @TanveerAlam Should your project_path be 'home/Desktop/test1' or '/home/Desktop/test1'?

Comment: Yes its '/home/Desktop/test1' beginning from '/'. I have edited my question above. Please check

Comment: @TanveerAlam Use new code and try again. I've updated my answer.